# How to find a specific device on a wifi network from android?

Tags: android, networking, ip, wifi

I'm looking at building a wireless data recording system that will take data measurements and transmit them to a host Android device over a wifi network.

I'm in the early planning stages and need to know is it possible on Android to search a local wifi network for my wireless data system (which will already be connected to network, don't worry about that aspect).  Is this possible and how would it be done?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at using something like multicast DNS to do the discovery. On Java you can use JmDNS (see http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmdns/ for source code: the examples are in the source code download). This would let you have your host system advertise its presence on the local wireless network and then your Android device can search for it and connect to it.

Comment: Wouldn't I have to setup the wireless network for zeroconf in order for this to work?  I'm just starting my networking research for this project so this may be a stupid question.

Comment: As long as you have a wireless Ethernet network you don't have to do anything more to get zeroconf working. Each node has to be running a multicast DNS service but other than that nothing special needs to be done for the network to get it to work. If you're running some exotic network substrate you're on your own there :)

Comment: It's just the nature of the corporate world that you can't mess with the network at all :)

Comment: Point. This is quite tame: shouldn't raise any flags. All Macs have zeroconf on by default, so if you have any Macs you already have mDNS traffic flying around.

Comment: Be careful with multicast. Some Android phones, like HTC Desire, are not able to receive multicast messages. They are dropped at the MAC Layer. I dont know why, seems to be for battery saving. Regarding Zeroconf: The devices send a "Hello" message (mc) and your zeroconf client listens on the mc group. so you will dynamically detect devices in your Wifi BSS.